# Change paper size in PDF on form submit

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm trying to change the page size in my script utilizing TCPDF on form submit. The value submitted is one of the following 'A4' or 'Letter'. I check and see the value posted successfully, however, when the document is generated it is always the same size, 'Letter' I believe. In my script I tried to change it in several ways:

```
if ($_POST['paper'] == 'A4') {
    define ('PDF_PAGE_FORMAT', 'A4');
} else {
    define ('PDF_PAGE_FORMAT', 'Letter');
}

$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

or

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, ($_POST['paper'] == 'A4' ? 'A4 : 'Letter'), true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

or

$pdf->AddPage("P", $_POST['paper']);

but to no avail. What am I missing?

Comment: Try `LETTER` rather than `Letter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe based from the static value from this [TCPDF repository file](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/master/include/tcpdf_static.php#L2247) the correct format is `LETTER` (in uppercase) instead of `Letter`.